# Click an area of a webpage given an X Y value

Tags: testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to click a pin I have on my application which uses Bing Maps V8. The pins which are placed on to the map do not appear in the DOM elements as they are directly rendered onto the Map by Bing Maps engine.

I was wondering is there a way I can tell Testcafe to click an X Y value - for example

```
testController.click(718,962);
```

The above X Y value is from [Selenium's IDE test recorder](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide)

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the Click action with [offset](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/action-options.html#click-action-options) to click a point on an area. For example:

```
t.click('body', { offsetX: X, offsetY: Y })
// or t.click('img', {offsetX: X, offsetY: Y})
```